# How to show all the pages of a pdf instead of just one in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf.js

I am having trouble showing all the pages of a PDF instead of one using pdf.js

This is the code that displays the pdf
I copied this code from Traversy Media's tutorial but it currently only prints out the first page and only goes to the next page when you click on the next page button. But I want to show all the pages of the PDF without the user having to click on next page

```
 <div class="top-bar">
                                          <button class="btn" id="prev-page">
                                            <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left"></i> Prev Page
                                          </button>
                                          <button class="btn" id="next-page">
                                            Next Page <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                                          </button>
                                          <span class="page-info">
                                            Page <span id="page-num"></span> of <span id="page-count"></span>
                                          </span>
                                        </div>

                                        <canvas id="pdf-render"></canvas>

                                        <script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

                                        <script>
                                          const url = 'pdfname.pdf';

                                          let pdfDoc = null,
                                            pageNum = 1,
                                            pageIsRendering = false,
                                            pageNumIsPending = null;

                                          const scale = 1.5,
                                            canvas = document.querySelector('#pdf-render'),
                                            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                                          // Render the page
                                          const renderPage = num => {
                                            pageIsRendering = true;

                                            // Get page
                                            pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(page => {
                                              // Set scale
                                              const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale });
                                              canvas.height = viewport.height;
                                              canvas.width = viewport.width;

                                              const renderCtx = {
                                                canvasContext: ctx,
                                                viewport
                                              };

                                              page.render(renderCtx).promise.then(() => {
                                                pageIsRendering = false;

                                                if (pageNumIsPending !== null) {
                                                  renderPage(pageNumIsPending);
                                                  pageNumIsPending = null;
                                                }
                                              });

                                              // Output current page
                                              document.querySelector('#page-num').textContent = num;
                                            });
                                          };

                                          // Check for pages rendering
                                          const queueRenderPage = num => {
                                            if (pageIsRendering) {
                                              pageNumIsPending = num;
                                            } else {
                                              renderPage(num);
                                            }
                                          };

                                          // Show Prev Page
                                          const showPrevPage = () => {
                                            if (pageNum <= 1) {
                                              return;
                                            }
                                            pageNum--;
                                            queueRenderPage(pageNum);
                                          };

                                          // Show Next Page
                                          const showNextPage = () => {
                                            if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
                                              return;
                                            }
                                            pageNum++;
                                            queueRenderPage(pageNum);
                                          };

                                          // Get Document
                                          pdfjsLib
                                            .getDocument(url)
                                            .promise.then(pdfDoc_ => {
                                              pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;

                                              document.querySelector('#page-count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

                                              renderPage(pageNum);
                                            })
                                            .catch(err => {
                                              // Display error
                                              const div = document.createElement('div');
                                              div.className = 'error';
                                              div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err.message));
                                              document.querySelector('body').insertBefore(div, canvas);
                                              // Remove top bar
                                              document.querySelector('.top-bar').style.display = 'none';
                                            });

                                          // Button Events
                                          document.querySelector('#prev-page').addEventListener('click', showPrevPage);
                                          document.querySelector('#next-page').addEventListener('click', showNextPage);
                                              </script> 
                                              <style>
                                                * {
                                            margin: 0;
                                            padding: 0;
                                          }

                                          .top-bar {
                                            background: #333;
                                            color: #fff;
                                            padding: 1rem;
                                          }

                                          .btn {
                                            background: coral;
                                            color: #fff;
                                            border: none;
                                            outline: none;
                                            cursor: pointer;
                                            padding: 0.7rem 2rem;
                                          }

                                          .btn:hover {
                                            opacity: 0.9;
                                          }

                                          .page-info {
                                            margin-left: 1rem;
                                          }

                                          .error {
                                            background: orangered;
                                            color: #fff;
                                            padding: 1rem;
                                          }
                                        </style>
                                           <link
                                              rel="stylesheet"
                                              href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css"
                                              integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr"
                                              crossorigin="anonymous"
                                            />
                                            <script src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
```

Any help will be much appreciated

thanks,

Arnav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can this.

```
const pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist");
const pdfWorker =  `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjsLib.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
const pdfPath = "/teste.pdf";

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfWorker;

const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(pdfPath);
loadingTask.promise
    .then(function (pdfDocument) {
        // Request a first page
        const viewer = document.getElementById("the-canvas");
        let renderTask;
        for(let page = 1; page <= pdfDocument.numPages; page++) {
            pdfDocument.getPage(page).then(function (pdfPage) {
                const viewport = pdfPage.getViewport({ scale: 1.0 });
                const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                canvas.width = viewport.width;
                canvas.height = viewport.height;
                const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                viewer.appendChild(canvas);
                renderTask = pdfPage.render({
                    canvasContext: ctx,
                    viewport,
                });
            });
        }
        return renderTask.promise;
    })
    .catch(function (reason) {
        console.error("Error: " + reason);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out  turns out it was a very simple answer 
but here's the code of the whole page

```
<!-- pdf viewer supportes on all browsers this script is mainly used to display all the page of pdf in scroll method . 
beacause norrmal click is already mentioned in pdf.js documentation -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div id="navbar" class="controls">
   <button type="button"  class="btn-zoom pls" onclick="zoomin()"><span>+</span> </button>
 <button type="button" class="btn-zoom min" onclick="zoomout()"><span>-</span> </button>
</div>
    <script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>
    <div id="pdf-viewer" class="pdf-viewer"></div>
</div>
<style>
  .pdf
  {
    over-flow:scroll;
    width:540px;
  }
  .pdf-viewer
  {
    width:auto;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:1px solid red;
  }
  canvas
  {
    width:100%;
  }
</style>
<script>
     // If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
    // header on that server.
    var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf';

    // Loaded via <script> tag, create shortcut to access PDF.js exports.
    var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

    // The workerSrc property shall be specified.
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

    var thePdf = null;
    var scale =2.3;

    pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdf) {
      thePdf = pdf;
      viewer = document.getElementById('pdf-viewer');

      for(page = 1; page <= pdf.numPages; page++) {
        canvas = document.createElement("canvas");    
        canvas.className = 'pdf-page-canvas';    
        viewer.appendChild(canvas);            
        renderPage(page, canvas);
      }

    });
    function renderPage(pageNumber, canvas) {
      thePdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
        viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;          
// page.render({canvasContext: canvas.getContext('2d'), viewport: viewport});
 page.render({canvasContext: canvas.getContext('2d'), viewport: viewport}).promise.then(function () {
 if (thePdf.numPages === pageNumber) 
// document.getElementById('loader').style.display=='none';
                    $('#loader').hide();
                    $('.pdf-viewer').show();
                });
      });
    }




           //zoom functionality
           function zoomin(){
        var myImg = document.getElementById("pdf-viewer");
        var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
        var currHeight = myImg.clientHeight;
        //if(currWidth == 2500) return false;
        // else{
        //    myImg.style.width = (currWidth + 100) + "px";
        //} 
        myImg.style.width = (currWidth + 50) + "px";
        myImg.style.height = (currHeight + 50) + "px";
    }
    function zoomout(){
        var myImg = document.getElementById("pdf-viewer");
        var currWidth = myImg.clientWidth;
        var currHeight = myImg.clientHeight;
        // if(currWidth == 100000) return false;
        //  else{
            myImg.style.width = (currWidth - 50) + "px";
            myImg.style.height= (currHeight- 50) + "px";
        // }
    }
</script>
```

Thanks,

Arnav